# Postpone annotation for subclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8, typing

It seems like postponed evaluations of type annotations as in [PEP 563](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/) don't work for the definition of subclasses.

This code works:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import List


class Foo:
    pass


class FooList(List[Foo]):
    pass


f = FooList()
```

On the other hand, this code fails with `NameError: name 'Foo' is not defined`:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import List


class FooList(List[Foo]):
    pass


class Foo:
    pass


f = FooList()
```

This is a toy example of course. The code I am working on is more complex, and there are dependencies between the classes which will not let me change their order. What is the best way to deal with this problem?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? The class `FooList` is not connected to `Foo` in any way... You are inheriting the `list` type...

Comment: I am trying to define a list that can only have `Foo`'s as items. In reality, I am using a more complex self-written collection class, but the idea is the same. The subclass is supposed to have some additional methods, which can be more specific because I know what the items are going to be.

Answer (score 1):

In `class FooList(List[Foo])`, `List[Foo]` is not an annotation. Annotations are a specific syntactical element, used after a `:` or `->`.

You will need to use a forward reference for `Foo` manually:

```
class FooList(List['Foo']):
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware of the fact that annotations require a `:` or `->`. What are the square brackets in `List[Foo]` then? I guess they are not used for indexing in this context?

Comment: @bbrot: On a syntactical level, they are in fact indexing.